# In MVVM Navigation will viewmodel be taken from UserControl.DataContext of MainWindow

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I use MVVM navigaion. I have Main Window, and I navigate to child user controls.
On the user controls I create instance of their viewmodel.
So I wonder, which instance of the viewmodel will be taken, the one created on the mainwindow, or 
the one from the usercontrol, and is it problematic, that I create two instances?
Main Window with DataTemplates:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cust:CustomersListViewModel}">
            <cust:CustomerListView></cust:CustomerListView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dealer:DealersViewModel}">
            <dealer:DealersView></dealer:DealersView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

I Create instances of child user controls :

```
  Customers.CustomersListViewModel customersViewModel = new Customers.CustomersListViewModel();
  Dealers.DealersViewModel dealersViewModel = new Dealers.DealersViewModel();
```

And I bind to child user controls with :
`
On the user controls I create viewmodel instance:

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:CustomersListViewModel></local:CustomersListViewModel>
  </UserControl.DataContext>
```

So is it problematic that I create to instances of view model?

Comment: Don't create your views and don't create two viewmodels for each. Create a viewmodel in the mainwindowviewmodel. Use that to datatemplate into view.  Like this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should not "create view-model instence" in the code of view.
In any case where appling `DataTemplate` by match the `TargetType`, the `DataContext` of the controls of `DataTemplate` will inherit the value from templated parent, because the `TargetType` of `DataTemplate` is matched by **Type** of the instance - this instance is that given object.

Value of DataContext => [Object] => GetType() => Match by `TargetType` => Apply `DataTemplate`, the `DataContext` is [Object]

A simple example:

```
<Window.Resource>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="local:TypeA">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueA}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="local:TypeB">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueB}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resource>
<ContentControl>
    <!-- The content is a TypeA object, will apply the TypeA DataTemplate -->
    <!-- displayed 100 -->
    <local:TypeA ValueA="100"/>
</ContentControl>
```

And what your code do:

```
<Window.Resource>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="local:TypeA">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueA}">
            <TextBlock.DataContext>
                <local:TypeA ValueA="50"/>
            </TextBlock.DataContext>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resource>
<ContentControl>
    <!-- The content is a TypeA object, will apply the TypeA DataTemplate -->
    <!-- displayed 50, because you create a new instance of TypeA in the DataTemplate -->
    <local:TypeA ValueA="100"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: The reason I create view model instance in chid view, is that it gives me intellisense, in the view's XAML

Comment: @jivangilad uh....intellisense just help you for coding... don't think it can follow your "ideas", and give you the "best practices"

Answer (score 0):

You should create this:

```
 <Window.Resources>
      <StackPanel>
            <cust:CustomerListView></cust:CustomerListView>
            <dealer:DealersView></dealer:DealersView>
      </StackPanel>
</Window.Resources>
```

and in your `UserControls` you should do this:

```
  //Create Object of ViewModel in CustomerListView
  DataContext = new Customers.CustomersListViewModel();

  //Create Object of ViewModel in DealersView
  DataContext = new Dealers.DealersViewModel();
```

Comment: I have found a solution for intellisense by using  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance myApp:Window2ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for intellisense by using d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance myApp:Window2ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"> 
So I dont need to create instance in runtime from the view